# Text editor with spell checker that ignores (X)HTML/CSS/javascript tags?

Tags: css, xhtml, validation, spell-checking

Do you know of any text editor that can be used with a spell checker which is smart enough to ignore XHML/CSS and javascript tags?

The requirements would be:

1. It must run in Linux;
2. It must be free and open source;
3. It doesn't need to have WYSIWYG capabilities, but they would be welcome.
4. It must have built in "tag skipping" capabilities or be configurable to skip (X)HTML tags, CSS and embedded Javascript;
5. It doesn't need to have a HTML validator, but if it does it will be a plus;

   I've tried to use spell checker plugins for Kate, HTML validators for Firefox, Eclipse's HTML editor, but I couldn't find a solution that have a speel checker that ignores hml tags.

Thanks for any help,
Luís

Answer (score 2):

Emacs + flyspell-prog-mode + [nxhtml-mode](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate this answer?

Answer (score 0):

[**Vim**](http://www.vim.org/). For example, I use the following settings:

```
set spell
set spelllang=en_gb
```

Comment: I agree, and you can install GVIM on Windows as well.  It is cross platform, and very lightweight.  And it's also one of the "old standards" used by veteran computer professionals...

Answer (score 0):

Although other people have cited other good text-based editors, some people might find a GUI application easier to learn.

There is the [BlueFish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) editor. It supports HTML, CSS, Javascript and other languages. I've just experimented a little more and its spell checker does ignore all HTML tags.

Edit: the spell checker doesn't ignore javascript, though. Other than that, it works.